# What is the throttling rate that GTalk applies to XMPP messages?

Tags: xmpp, google-talk

Even after throttling down to one message per second, after about 20 messages GTalk starts bouncing XMPP messages with ...

```
<error type="cancel" code="503"><service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" /></error>
```

What is the maximum send rate for XMPP messages through Google Talk?

Answer (score 0):

i too experienced throttling from talk.google.com, but i can't find any documentation on it. The client from within gmail doesn't seem to have that same restriction. I was able to do paste and enter quickly to simulate it.